# Angular 4 get height of element thats hidden with *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tz1yjd?file=styles.css

So I have a component that is hidden with *ngIf, it shows when a button is clicked.

Is it possible to get the height of this component before it is shown with OnInit.

Or how do I get the height when it is shown after the button is clicked.

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() parent: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('block')
  block: ElementRef;

  show: boolean = false
  blockHeight: number

  constructor(){ }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.blockHeight = this.block.nativeElement.clientHeight;
  }


  showBlock(){
    this.show = !this.show
    this.blockHeight = this.block.nativeElement.clientHeight;
  }
```

Comment: i think you can't get it ..cause it's NOT rendered in the DOM ..instead use [hidden] if you need it .. hope it helps you!

Comment: Yes I believe federico is right. In general, anytime you're trying to read calculated properties from the DOM like width or height, you should use the 'AfterViewInit' life cycle hook instead of 'OnInit', as the view isn't fully initialized in OnInit and many properties will be undefined. But like he said, the ngIf prevents it from being rendered so you won't be able to read the height until its rendered. Use another method like binding to hidden or changing visibilty.

Comment: I thought about [hidden] but the actual code has a lot element that use *ngIf that I need to find height of. Hidden would add them all to the DOM

Comment: AfterViewInit doesn't work here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uja1kz?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts The showBlock does but only after thr seconf click.

Comment: I'd take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170449/angular-4-using-setter-on-viewchild As the others have mentioned, [hidden] will keep it on the dom, but if you need it OFF the dom you can have the @ViewChild on a setter and it will be called when it is placed on the dom. Then in there you can have something get the element's height. Just a note though, if you're using a component and not a native html element you'll need to replace ElementRef with the Component's class.

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer will help somehow in the future. Sometimes you could use the simple strategy to render an element but control the visibility of it with the class binding

```
[class.d-none]="conditionChecker()"
```

or

```
[class.invisible]="conditionChecker()"
```